# Matplotlib - How to edit the same plot with different functions?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a complicated figure using calls to different functions. Im am working inside ipython notebook.

For the sake of the example, say that first I want to create a figure with a call to a function that does a scatter plot.

```
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 def background():
     fig = plt.figure()
     ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
     ax.scatter(np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10))

     return fig, ax

 fig, ax = background()
```

Then, I want to overlay the next layer on top of my scatter plot. My understanding is that I should reuse the axes that I just got back from `background()`.  What I'm currently trying to do is

```
 # Eventually, I would put the next lines inside a function
 ax.plot(np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10), '-')

 # next I want to show the updated figure
 fig.canvas.draw_idle() # doesn't work
 plt.show()             # doesn't work
```

What is the correct way of showing the updated plot?

I'm working with ipython notebook version 3.2.1, matplotlib version 2.02 and just in case anyone waoders, I did call `%matplotlib inline` before starting.

Comment: `draw_idle()` has no meaning with the inline backend. `plt.show()` by default only works within the same cell. However, just stating the figure handle will show the figure; type `fig` and run the cell.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thank you! That is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, that was embarrassing. As correctly pointed out by @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest, just calling `fig` in a cell will show the updated figure *if I was calling the code in different cells.*

If I had tested my code in the same notebook cell the way I was doing it (using `ax` to update the plot) would have worked. For reference, the whole thing looks like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def background():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax.scatter(np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10))

    return fig, ax

def foreground(ax):
   ax.plot(np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10))

# Calling both functions
fig, ax = background()
foreground(ax)

# because I'm working in the notebook no need to call anything else
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    def background(**kwargs):
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        ax.scatter(np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10))

        return fig, ax

   #Now let's call the background function with params to plot. 

   fig,ax = background()
   ax.plot(np.random.rand(10), np.random.rand(10), '-')
   fig.canvas.draw_idle()
   plt.show()
```

gives the outputs: 
[image]

I think this would help.

Comment: I don't really get it, what is the point of adding `ax.plot(**kwargs)`? It's not doing anything in your code at the moment right?

Comment: Yes, you're right, there seems no logical point here of that. Thank you for the pointer.