# matplotlib reusing axes in Jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, figure, axes

This is a question I have been wanting an answer to for a while. I have spent much time searching for answers on SO. This question is related: [Matplotlib - How to edit the same plot with different functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711438/matplotlib-how-to-edit-the-same-plot-with-different-functions).

I am guessing that there is a simple explanation for this and I am interested to know about it.

**The question is:**

Can I display an axes in Jupyter in one cell and then display it again in another cell? It seems that I cannot. It seems that once an axes is displayed it becomes "spent" in some way, like it is one-shot tool. I can add additional plots and re-display the *figure* (without any axes), but the axes itself is "spent".

Here is an example to show this behavior:

Using Jupyter, I can do the following to create a plot in *the first cell*:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

some_x_data = [11.4, 23.11, 27.93, 33.47, 45.98, 47.23, 53.84, 65.34, 87.23]
some_y_data = [(5.3 * x * (10 - x/10)) for x in some_x_data]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.plot(some_x_data, some_y_data)
```

The plot displays:

[image: Matplotlib line plot]

Now, in *another cell*, I wish to re-display the axes again, so I do the following:

```py
ax
```

But no axes are displayed. Instead the return value is:

```
<AxesSubplot:>
```

However, if instead of `ax`, I run a cell with `fig`, then I see the figure but without axes:

```py
fig
```

[image: Image of original axes but with no x or y axis]

**Next** I try adding a new plot to the axes in another cell:

```py
ax.scatter([40, 100], [900, 1000])
```

Again, no figure is shown but a return value is generated:

```
<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7fb5fc0a7c10>
```

I can then see the updated figure by calling `fig` in another cell, but again without any axes attached:

[image: Original figure but with two additional scatter points added but without any x or y axes]

*What is going on here behind the scenes? Why can I not just re-display the axes?*

Thank you for any insight folks can give.

**P.S. I am assuming that this is a duplicate question but I simply cannot find the answer. If this is a duplicate, please add a link.**

Comment: Some of the coverage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76707536/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60269307/8508004) can help you. For the latter one it is helpful to keep in mind that Seaborn is built on matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

## Intro

Late, but I had a similar problem and there was no clear answer. Not sure what causes it, but any memory stored by `pyplot` is completely cleared between jupyter notebook cells using the standard interactive mode, whilst calling `pyplot.show()` only works once for some reason. I assume this is the same magic which allows one to happily plot with impunity between cells without incurring any problems. For instance:

---

#### Cell 1

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline 
plt.ion()

plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
```

Should produce a normal plot.

#### Cell 2

```py
plt.plot()
```

Empty plot. Does not follow from the previous plot.

---

## Answer

To prevent it clearing, use the [`plt.ioff()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ioff.html) command, *and explicitly state the figure* wherever you want to show the plot. Try the example below:

---

#### Cell 1

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline
plt.ioff()

fig = plt.Figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
fig
```

This should show the figure with one line. Note that if `plt.show` is used instead, it causes [issues downstream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36267710/14764023).

#### Cell 2

```py
ax.plot([0, 1], [1, 0])
fig
```

Should show both lines. Not very intuitive at all!

## Notes

I'm not sure why in your example there are no axes being displayed on your figure, but the way I tested showed the figure with the correct axes.

---